# SQL transformation: multiple rows to one row

Tags: sql, string, aggregate-functions

If I have a table like this

```
customer  |   product
--------------------------------
c1.       |.  ginger
c1.       |.  lemon
c2.       |.  apple
c1        |.  iron
```

How do you recommend using SQL to transform into a table indexed on customer like this:

```
customer  |   all_products
--------------------------------
c1.       | ginger, lemon, iron
c2.       | apple
```

Comment: Which sql engine are you using and what version?

Comment: The answer will depend on your RDBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracles, etc.)

Comment: in mysql you could use group_concat() function, but as mentioned earlier it depends on your engine

Answer (score 1):

You are describing string aggregation. In standard, we would use `listagg()`:

```
select customer, 
    listagg(product, ', ') within group(order by product) as all_products
from mytable
group by customer
```

The syntax varies across databases, but most have an equivalent syntax.

Oracle supports the standard function.

Postgres has `string_agg()`:

```
string_agg(product, ', ' order by product)
```

SQL Server:

```
string_agg(product, ', ') within group(order by product)
```

MySQL has `group_concat()`:

```
group_concat(product order by product separator ', ')
```

And so on.